# remove_cart_item(), foreach works, direct does not

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have two functions to remove items from cart. One that accepts multiple values and another that only accepts one.

```
function woomps_remove_subs($sub_remove){
    global $woocommerce;
    foreach($sub_remove as $x => $y) {
        $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id($y);
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);   
    }       
}

function woomps_remove_sub($sub_remove){
    global $woocommerce;
        $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id($sub_remove);
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);           
}
```

- woomps_remove_subs - removes cart items.
- woomps_remove_sub - does not remove cart items.

I logged the $y and $sub_remove before generate_card_id and the values are in same format.

Why does the first code snippet work in regards to the second?

Comment: The functions look good to me, can you also add the parameters with which you are calling each function?

Comment: I want to see what is in $ex in both cases. woomps_remove_subs($ex) and woomps_remove_sub($ex). Please paste that, the code above looks fine, so I think the problem is how you call it.

Comment: I dont know if i completely understood...but:

I call first one like this: woomps_remove_subs($ex);
ChromePhp::log("subs: ".$sub_remove); right after function executes outputs: subs: Array                And after foreach subs: 222

woomps_remove_sub($sub_remove); 
ChromePhp::log("sub: ".$sub_remove); right after function executes outputs: sub: 221

Comment: When you call woomps_remove_sub($ex), is $ex an integer? If it is not then that is why it doesn't work.

Comment: You are correct. It was a string. I converted it to int with this code:
          $sub_remove_int = intval($sub_remove);
          woomps_remove_sub($sub_remove_int);
But it still not deleting. hemmmm...

Comment: I also looked at the value passed to generate_cart_id for the other function that works. That is also a string.

Comment: As i get the $cart_item_id succesfully each time before i try and remove the item from cart it is strange that it does not remove. It seems to me that their is some validation im missing. If you see something here: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#960-982 i would very much appriciate the help!

Comment: Try to pass the id that you say it doesn't work si the woomps_remove_sub, to the woomps_remove_subs as : woomps_remove_subs( array( $id ) ). It shouldn't work either, and if it doesn't work then the problem is your id.

Comment: Thank you very much for a little perspective. I tried what you say and found out i had forgot a little script in the background. The error was at my side. Credz to you for holding out :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The PHP code is correct. It was an error in my enviroment.

Thank you.